# Possible input focus bug in Mobile Safari?

Tags: cordova, input, keyboard, focus

I am using the following plugin to create a virtual keyboard within a phonegap application:

http://mottie.github.com/Keyboard/mobile.html

This is working 100% fine apart from the cursor NOT appearing ONLY in Mobile Safari.

Try it, point your iOS device to that URL and watch how there's no cursor at all.

However, when you open that URL within any other desktop browser (including desktop Safari) the cursor blinks away like it's meant to.

My question is whether there's anything I can do to display the cursor in mobile safari or whether it's a bug/or requirement by Apple. Also keep in mind we don't want the native keyboard to show at all so tapping in the input field is out of the question as it spawns the native keyboard.

We want to use the virtual keyboard ONLY within our application.

**UPDATE:**

We are 99.9% away from submitting our application to the AppStore and we just don't want to deploy without the cursor blinking. It just looks horrible and from a usability perspective we're not even sure Apple would approve such functionality.

Our test devices are running: 5.1.1 (9B206).

**EDIT:**

As this may be a bug with the actual library itself. I have posted an issue on Github as well:

[Mobile Safari not display caret/cursor](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/issues/105)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like it's a bug within Mobile Safari and there is no current fix unfortunately:

[Mobile Safari not display caret/cursor](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/issues/105#issuecomment-8531265)